# Scala equivalent of java.util.Scanner

Tags: parsing, scala

I am very familiar with using `java.util.Scanner` with `next()`, `hasNext()`, `nextInt()`, `nextLine()`, and the like to parse input.

Is there something else I should use in Scala?

This data isn't structured according to a grammar; it's more ad-hoc than that.

For example, lets say I had a inventory. Each line of input starts with the name, then has the quantity of those items, then has the ids for those items

```
Firetruck 2 A450M A451M
Machine 1 QZLT
Keyboard 0
```

I see that `Console` has methods such as `readInt()`, but that reads an entire line of input; the equivalent of `nextInt()` doesn't seem to exist.

`java.util.Scanner` obviously does the trick. But is there something else I should use (for example, something that returns Scala rather than Java types)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there is no equivalent Scala implementation. But I don't see a reason for one as java.util.Scanner would work perfectly fine and all java primitives types would be converted to Scala types implicitly.

So as for "for example, something that returns Scala rather than Java types", Scanner will return scala types when used in scala.

Comment: "Scanner will return scala types when used in scala". Oh, duh of course it will. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[better-files](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files#scanner) is a Scala library that provides faster, safer and more idiomatic replacement for `java.util.Scanner` and provides more operations like peeking and scanning.

Link: https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files#scanner

Code sample:

```
val data = (home / "Desktop" / "stocks.tsv") << s"""
| id  Stock Price   Buy
| ---------------------
| 1   AAPL  109.16  false
| 2   GOOGL 566.78  false
| 3   MSFT   39.10  true
""".stripMargin

val scanner: Scanner = data.newScanner.skip(lines = 2)

assert(scanner.peekLine == Some(" 1   AAPL  109.16  false"))
assert(scanner.peek == Some("1"))
assert(scanner.nextInt == Some(1))
assert(scanner.peek == Some("AAPL"))
assert(scanner.nextString() == Some("AAPL"))
assert(scanner.nextInt() == None)
assert(scanner.nextDouble() == Some(109.16))
assert(scanner.nextBoolean() == Some(false))

while(scanner.hasNext) {
  println(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.next(), scanner.nextDouble(), scanner.nextBoolean())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the input data denoted by spaces and newlines this can be nicely done with `map` and `split` on each line from `input`.

```
def input =
"""Firetruck 2 A450M A451M
Machine 1 QZLT
Keyboard 0"""

case class Item(name: String, quantity: Int, ids: Array[String]) 

scala> input.lines.map(_.split(" ")).map(split => Item(split(0), split(1).toInt, split.takeRight(2))).toList

res0: List[Item] = List(Item(Firetruck,2,[Ljava.lang.String;@6608842e), Item(Machine,1,[Ljava.lang.String;@391e1c57), Item(Keyboard,0,[Ljava.lang.String;@67d6b10c))

scala>res0.foreach(println(_)) 

Item(Firetruck,2,[Ljava.lang.String;@6608842e)
Item(Machine,1 [Ljava.lang.String;@391e1c57)
Item(Keyboard,0,[Ljava.lang.String;@67d6b10c)
```

Comment: s/denoted/delimited and s/takeRight/drop