# Read elements of different types at the same time

Tags: scala

I want to read from the input lines which have one `Char` and then two `Int` elements, like this one:

```
A 1 4
```

So far, I thought about reading it like this:

```
val Array(mark, begin, end) = readLine.split(" ")
```

Then, I am making type conversion. This is VERY ugly however.

Is there a nicer way of reading characters of different types from an input line?

Comment: Use the Java Scanner class? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Or this answer contains a link to a Scala equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32812821/21755

Comment: Shapeless + magic is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982555/convert-scala-liststring-listobject-into-model-hlist-tuple/34996606#34996606

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions as extractors and a custom extractor to convert to int:

```
object int {
  def unapply(s: String) = try {
    Some(s.toInt)
  } catch {
    case e: NumberFormatException => None
  }
}

val pat = """([^ ]+) (\d+) (\d+)""".r
val pat(mark,int(begin),int(end)) = readLine
```

A match statement might be better than the assignment if you want to handler errors. (Of course you could catch the exception.)

Comment: Why is that better than `split`? The OP has already said the line has a fixed format, and this is not better on the type conversion

Comment: Well, I do not know, what exactly he finds ugly about his solution. I like this one as it does a bit more input validation. Especially you would know that toInt on the Strings would succeed (except if they are too long). It would also be possible, to do the convertion by a custom extractor.

Comment: "Then, I am making type conversion. This is VERY ugly however."

Comment: Well, he might refer to the type conversion, he might just as well refer to the hole approach. I do not really care though. If he likes my answer fine, if not, he can go for other suggestions. this is, how i would do it, if i head a lot of cases like this.